# dotNet watcher, watch only .dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-watcher

I use the command `dotnet watch run` while developing dotnet core applications. However, I want the watcher only to watch if the .dll file in the bin folder has changed, and only then should it rebuild the application. In other words, I want the dotnet console app to re-run when I build my project/solution.

I tried to override the default behaviour of the watcher in the .csproj to accomplish this, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-files-list-to-watch).

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Watch Include = "**/*.dll">

   <Watch Exclude = "**/*.cs">
   <Watch Exclude = "**/*.resx">
   <Watch Exclude = "*.csprj">
</ItemGroup
```

but it doesn't work.
Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You missed the last `>`. Maybe that was just a typo when you were copying over code to SO.

You could try putting it all in one line like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Watch Include="**/*.dll" Exclude="**/*.cs;**/*.resx;**.*.csproj">
</ItemGroup>
```

I just tested this on a solution of mine which has 11 projects, and it worked. I had to add it to every csproj file though (and yes, I have .csproj files, not .csprj, not sure .csprj is even a thing, perhaps another typo).

Reference - [docs](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/release/2.1/src/dotnet-watch/README.md#msbuild).

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I never managed to fix the issue and just left it. I will try your solution though

Comment: I thought so :D But I guess since I found the question, and found the answer somewhere else.. if someone else finds your question, it might help! Cheers